# ParsefacebookUtils returning wrong values in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, parsefacebookutils

for my android application i wanted to integrate a facebook login, so i did exactly what is here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial

Everything seems to work fine however the values which are stored in the parse backend are not convenient, here is for example what i get after login with my facebook account:
emailVerified:empty
username:adGdJMxcCQCAo2.....
authData: {"facebook":{"access_token":"CAAMBDxU3HgUBAMYQ8q2mnjDqeKBz2sw......","expiration_date":"...","id":"1015353..."}}

Sorry i still can't upload pictures..
Is this normal?

i'm using parseFacebookUtils 1.9.4
parse 1.9.4

Comment: can you post code so i can tell you where you doing wrong

Comment: the same here: (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial/tree/master/IntegratingFacebookTutorial-Android/IntegratingFacebookTutorial)

Comment: only the versions are differents, they are using 1.9.2 and i'm using 1.9.4, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what i had done for `facebook` `parse.com` login

**LoginFragment.java**

```
private ParseLoginConfig config;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, 1);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login, container, false);
    config = ParseLoginConfig.fromBundle(getArguments(), getActivity());
    return rootView;
}

private void loginUsingFacebook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (config.isFacebookLoginNeedPublishPermissions()) {

        ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(
                getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"),
                facebookLoginCallbackV4);
    } else {
        ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(
                getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"),
                facebookLoginCallbackV4);
    }
}


private LogInCallback facebookLoginCallbackV4 = new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (isActivityDestroyed()) {
            return;
        }

        if (user == null) {
            loadingFinish();
            if (e != null) {
                showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_facebook_login_failed_toast);
                debugLog(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_facebook_login_failed)
                        + e.toString());
            }
        } else if (user.isNew()) {
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject fbUser,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            /*
                             * If we were able to successfully retrieve the
                             * Facebook user's name, let's set it on the
                             * fullName field.
                             */
                            Log.e("facebook User", fbUser.toString());
                            final ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser
                                    .getCurrentUser();
                            if (fbUser != null
                                    && parseUser != null
                                    && fbUser.optString("name").length() > 0) {
                                parseUser.put(USER_OBJECT_NAME_FIELD,
                                        fbUser.optString("name"));
                                parseUser.put(USER_OBJECT_EMAIL_FIELD,
                                        fbUser.optString("email"));
                                parseUser
                                        .saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(
                                                    ParseException e) {
                                                if (e != null) {
                                                    debugLog(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_facebook_login_user_update_failed)
                                                            + e.toString());
                                                }
                                                ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation
                                                        .getCurrentInstallation();
                                                installation
                                                        .put(BaseFragment.INSTALLATION_UNIQUE_ID,
                                                                parseUser
                                                                        .getUsername());
                                                installation
                                                        .saveInBackground();
                                                loginSuccess();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
        } 
    }
};
```

**Note :**  **Remove toast messages and and text me if any query!!**

Comment: this part is done also in UserDetailActivity.java :/

Comment: then try with new facebook key

Comment: I think this explain the problem :  **This is related to the new update to the Facebook API. With new privacy changes being applied, when a user approves an app, instead of giving the app the user's Facebook id, an app scoped-id is generated and assigned.

However users that have approved an app previous to the update continue to get their own facebook id. I don't think parse has updated their data-browser to demonstrate these changes since a user's facebook-id for an app is no longer a real facebook-id..** I don't know how to resolve that : /