# Facebook Login Using Parse SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to use `ParseFacebook` Login in my app. I have successfully created a login using facebook sdk. now I want to do it using `ParseSDK`.
On `LoginButton` Click, it throws an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.Hashmap can not cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

Please Guide me in a right way.
Thanks

Here is my Code snippet:

```
    static List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    mPermissions.add("public_profile");
    mPermissions.add("email");
    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebook_Login.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(e == null)
                    {
                        if(user == null)
                           {
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Cancelled the Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }

                           else if(user.isNew())
                           {
                               User_Info();
                           }

                           else
                           {
                               Current_User();

                           }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());

                    }
                }


            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you post your click listener

Comment: post code in which you store your `json` response in `Hashmap`

Comment: where is `User_Info();` and `Current_User();` ?

Comment: Its not going in User_Info or into Current_User, it goes into Exception

Comment: post code of mPermissions??

Comment: please check mPermissions

Comment: you code is okey.!! might be error happening some where else. You can rerfer this. look at my answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114046/parsefacebookutils-returning-wrong-values-in-parse/32120192#32120192)

Comment: Can you provide your entire stack trace? Also, the SDK is opensourced, so you can also take a investigate why the exception is throwing.